# How to reference the return value of a perl sub

Tags: perl, syntax, reference, return-value

The code:

```
my $compare = List::Compare->new(\@hand, \@new_hand);
print_cards("Discarded", $compare->get_Lonly()) if ($verbose);
```

`print_cards` expects (scalar, reference to array).
`get_Lonly` returns array. What's the syntax to convert that to a reference so I can pass it to print_cards?  `\@{$compare->getLonly()}` doesn't work, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want

```
print_cards("Discarded", [$compare->get_Lonly])
```

Subroutines don't return arrays, they return a list of values. We can create an array reference with `[...]`.

The other variant would be to make an explicit array

```
if ($verbose) {
  my @array = $compare->get_Lonly;
  print_cards("Discarded", \@array)
}
```

The first solution is a shortcut of this.

---

The `@{ ... }` is a dereference operator. It expects an array reference. This doesn't work as you think if you give it a list.